# Combining rows from CSV files in pandas list

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I am currently in a python class and am struggling with one of the assignments.  The goal is to write a program that finds median total home values for each State from a `CSV` from which lists were imported using pandas and print them in a certain format.  One of the first issues I am having, among many others, is combining rows from the `CSV`.  There are multiple rows for the same state, however, I need to find the median for the entire state and am not sure where to even begin.  I honestly am not even sure how to tie the rows in the first place, even before combing them.

Comment: What *do* you have? Have you been able to construct a dataframe from the CSV? Have you played around with groupby for the same state?

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.DataFrame({'state':['NSW','NSW','Vic','Qld','Qld','Vic','Vic','Vic','Qld','Vic','Qld','NSW'],
         'price':pd.np.random.rand(12)
        }).groupby('state').median()
```

Hope this gets you started. I've created a very simple data frame. You would use the read_csv function to create your data frame.

It is  grouping by the categorical variable - 'state' and then applying the median function to each group